# Cube won't render BLENDER

Tags: blender, modeling

I am using blender to make a character, but every time I add a mesh cube, it won't render. I've done several attempts to make it work, but it just won't. I'm sure I'm not the only one with this problem.

Comment: Is the cube in front of the camera? Press 0 on the numpad  to go into camera view and see what is visible. You could have enabled the [compositor or sequencer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5286/935) without setting them up.

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work, what I meant to say is during editing it only shows up as a point, if you need anything else just ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see it in the 3d viewer but not in the render, check in the list in the Outliner where you have all your objects and see if the little camera is clicked on.

if you can't see it in the 3d viewer but you have the point try to scale using S